# Vue JS returning [Object object] on console.log and Undefined on JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js, axios

So I am writing this Vue.JS code to display a data aquired by PHP from a server. The PHP returns a JSON object to the Vue and the VUE has to display it. My current code is:

```
  axiosPost();
}
function axiosPost()
{
 axios.post(
  './ConversationGetter.php',
  {
    function2call: 'getRecord',
    id: 1,
    access: this.accesstoken
  }

)
.then(response =>  {this.data=response.data;
console.log(response.data);
console.log("Response From VUE JS"+this.data);

})
.catch(error => {});
}
```

The Problem is, First `console.log` prints the Response data properly. But the second `console.log` displays the this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

If I use JSON.parse while displaying the data, it shows this:

```
undefined
```

Comment: Can you post content of response.data?

Comment: Yes. Give me a Second.

Comment: because `console.log('some string' + [someObject, someObject, etc])` coerces the array of objects in this.data to be an array of strings, and objects as strings become `'object Object'` - i.,e ignore the second console.log, it is completely as expected, the data is correct - use `console.log('some string', [someObject, someObject, etc])` ... notice the `,` instead of the `+` ... and your console.log will be what you expected in the first place

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth - the content is completely and utterly irrelevant

Comment: may you use JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 5):

"+" operator converting as string in second console statement. Please change it to "," as below?

```
console.log("Response From VUE JS", this.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `JSON.parse` .. Just use `response.data` direct. If you want to see actual data use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))`

Comment: JSON.stringify still returns [Object object]

Comment: If this is a webapi response, you can view structure in Network tab of the browser to inspect response structure or just `console.log(response.data)`